# Best way execute code according enum value

Tags: java, coding-style

The following code is an example of my problem.
I would like to simplify the code without having to repeat the call for the same methods, on different switch statements.

```
public void simulate(String given, Status status) {
    switch (status){
        case A:
            simulateA(given);
            break;
        case B:
            simulateA(given);
            simulateB(given);
            break;
        case C:
            simulateA(given);
            simulateB(given);
            simulateC(given);
            break;
    }
```

PS 1: The order of the calling methods matters!

PS 2: I am not looking for another way of doing the switch, I am looking for another way of modelling the problem, maybe using some kind of class composition with the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first `status` is A you can do something like this:

```
public void simulate(String given, Status status) {
   if (status != Status.A) {
     int indexOfStatus = status.ordinal();
     simulate(given, Status.values()[indexOfStatus - 1]);
   }
    
   switch (status){
      case A:
        simulateA(given);
        break;
      case B:
        simulateB(given);
        break;
      case C:
        simulateC(given);
        break;
    // here you still need to put all your "simulateX" calls but without repetitions
   }
}
```

Comment: This executes the methods in reverse order.

Comment: @VGR I run the code before to answer, it executes in correct order

Comment: Ah, yes, you’re right.  Make a minor edit to your answer (even just some extra space) so I can undo my downvote.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the nature of your `enum` but if you have many simulation calls you could forgo the switch statement and do it like this.  But there is nothing wrong with your current approach. This would also change slightly if your methods were static and not instance.  The one advantage of this is that it has the potential to scale.

There are many other ways to to this.  You could have a list of method references and the `enum` arguments could be variable arrays of which methods to call by index.

```
public class Simulations {
    
    static List<BiConsumer<Simulations, String>> sims =
            List.of(Simulations::simulateA, Simulations::simulateB,
                    Simulations::simulateC);
    
    enum Status {
        A(1), B(2), C(3);
        private int val;
        private Status(int v) {
            this.val = v;
        }
        public int getVal() {
            return val;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Simulations simulation = new Simulations();
        simulation.simulate("A", Status.A);
        System.out.println();
        simulation.simulate("B", Status.B);
        System.out.println();
        simulation.simulate("C", Status.C);
    }
    
    public void simulate(String given, Status status) {
        for (int i = 0; i < status.getVal(); i++) {
            sims.get(i).accept(this, given);
        }
    }
    
    public void simulateA(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    
    public void simulateB(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    
    public void simulateC(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the order of simulations always cascades "downwards", e.g. Simulating an B is simulating an A plus some extra's. This matches an inheritance pattern, e.g. a Mammal is an Animal with some extras. Thus, letting simulations inherit from each other fixes the pattern:

```
interface Simulation
{
    void simulate( final String given );
}

class ASimulation implements Simulation
{
    @Override
    public void simulate( String given )
    {
        // simulate this given!
    }
}

class BSimulation extends ASimulation
{
    @Override
    public void simulate( String given )
    {
        super.simulate( given );
        // simulate this given some more!
    }
}

class CSimulation extends BSimulation
{
    @Override
    public void simulate( String given )
    {
        super.simulate( given );
        // simulate this given even more!
    }
}
```

Note that this is fragile, as all inheritance trees are. Another solution can be achieved with composition and delegation. This is called a chain:

```
class LeafSimulation
        implements Simulation
{
    @Override
    public void simulate( String given )
    {
        // simulate this given!
    }
}

class ChainedSimulation
        implements Simulation
{
    private final Simulation delegate;

    ChainedSimulation( final Simulation delegate )
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void simulate( String given )
    {
        delegate.simulate( given );
        // simulate this given some more!
    }
}
```

To instantiate the chain, use the following order:

```
final var aSimulation = new LeafSimulation();
final var bSimulation = new ChainedSimulation( aSimulation );
final var cSimulation = new ChainedSimulation( bSimulation );
```

This code approaches the problem statement more naturally and eliminates the repetition, but it is not concise.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set up a mapping of status values to method calls, you can use a [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html) or [EnumSet.range](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#range(E,E)) to get the enum values after a particular value:

```
Map<Status, Consumer<String>> simulators = new EnumMap<>(Map.of(
    Status.A, this::simulateA,
    Status.B, this::simulateB,
    Status.C, this::simulateC));

if (!simulators.keySet().equals(EnumSet.allOf(Status.class))) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        "Not all Status values have simulators defined.");
}

// ...

SortedSet<Status> all = new TreeSet<>(EnumSet.allOf(Status.class));
Collection<Status> remainingValues = all.tailSet(status);

// Or:
//Status[] allStatuses = Status.values();
//Status lastStatus = allStatuses[allStatuses.length - 1];
//Collection<Status> remainingValues = EnumSet.range(status, lastStatus);

for (Status s : remainingValues) {
    simulators.get(s).accept(given);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider, which avoids `switch` / `if`. Declare a map of actions per `Status` value which can be used with a `getOrDefault` lookup default for unhandled values:

```
Consumer<String> simA = this::simulateA;
Map<Status, Consumer<String>> actions = new EnumMap<>(Map.of(
        Status.A, simA,
        Status.B, simA.andThen(this::simulateB),
        Status.C, simA.andThen(this::simulateB).andThen(this::simulateC)
));
actions.getOrDefault(status, s -> {}).accept(given);
```

If you want to guard against missing / unhandled mappings you should validate the map (as in @VGR answer) or swap the no-operation default with an exception handler:

```
actions.getOrDefault(status,
    s -> { throw new RuntimeException("Missing action for status: "+status); }
).accept(given);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the fallthrough mechanism of switch statement. refer to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-fall-through-switch-statements)

In your example, the code can be(not tested):

#### Edited:

```java
public void simulate(String given, Status status) {
    switch (status){
        case C:
            simulateC(given);
        case B:
            simulateB(given);
        case A:
            simulateA(given);
    }
}
```

#### Original(Wrong):

```java
public void simulate(String given, Status status) {
    switch (status){
        case A:
            simulateA(given);
        case B:
            simulateB(given);
        case C:
            simulateC(given);
    }
}
```

When the reader has the fallthrough concept in mind, the code above is cleaner and easier to read than the code in question. But that is not always the case. My recommendation would be to restructure your code so as to eliminate both the repetitive calls and the fallthroughs.

Comment: if status is A then all methods run ?

Comment: This is the opposite of wanted behavior, he wants for A only A, for B AB and for C ABC.
With your code would obtain: A -> ABC, B -> BC, C -> C.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to write simulateA(given) to all your cases, just moved it to top

```
public void simulate(String given, Status status) {
   simulateA(given);
   switch (status){
     case C:
       simulateC(given);
     case B:
       simulateB(given);
       break;
     case A:
       break;
 }}
```

Comment: This won't work since you're calling them in a different order.  e.g. `A,C,B` when status `C`